# Создание графических интерфейсов и рисование графиков

Tags: c#, c++, c

Задание: необходимо написать программу для рисования сложных графиков (циклоиды и все в этом роде), все было бы хорошо, но за год обучения нас учили писать только на чистом C под консоль. А тут вдруг нужно графический интерфейс, рисование графиков, да еще это все должно не ломаться и масштабироваться относительно окна, так еще и анимация будет.

Подскажите, как вообще работать с графическим интерфейсом и какие средства для этого использовать? Знаю, что есть такая вещь как `Qt`, знаю что есть `MFC` и `WinAPI` (*насколько я знаю, он сниться в кошмарах неокрепшим умам начинающих программистов*), но что лучше, и какие еще существуют библиотеки или среды, которые упростят эту задачу? Также, если потребуется, могу полистать и подучить С++ или С# (но сроки горят).

Comment: Если сроки горят, попробуйте объяснить преподавателю, что за 5 минут написанию графических приложений, обладая опытом только консольных, не учатся. Мне кажется, что C# и какие-нибудь WinForms подошли бы, но это я программирую 10 лет на C# и мне легко говорить, а вам надо с нуля переучиваться.

Comment: Времени, конечно, не 5 минут, а 2 недели(и то если преподаватели согласятся, а по умолчанию 1 неделя). Вы думаете кого - то волнует что мы там умеем, а что нет... Сказали если не можете в gui, пишите под консоль, но это, по моему, высшая степень извращения

Comment: Помню, когда возникали подобные задачи по учебе, использовал для быстрой реализации среду Builder C++. Там есть очень удобные встроенные виджеты для отрисовки графиков.

Comment: @user213904: По факту между графиками в консоли и GUI нет большой разницы. Ну пиксель в консоли покрупнее и неквадратный, при пересчёте координат придётся делить на размер.

Comment: Только нужна библиотека произвольного доступа к консоли. С потоковым выводом будет сложнее.

Comment: Дмитрий, к сожалению в выборе сред мы ограничены. На выбор только VS или Qt

Comment: Насколько я понял, графики вам нужны "научные"? имею в виду, не "офисные" диаграммы? И второе уточнение -- а вам точно необходим графический интерфейс? ведь графики можно генерировать и из консоли -- через тот же gnuplot например.

Comment: если вам нужно лишь графики вывести, то зачем городитьтGUI когда есть GNU/plot

Answer (score 2):

Каждый будет тянуть одеяло в сторону своего любимого фреймворка, и я не буду исключением. В Qt 5.7 [графики](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html) (в том числе и [в 3D](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-index.html)) доступны, что называется из коробки. Имеется набор примеров, содержащих полностью готовый код. Гистограммы, линейные, полярные и прочее. Поддерживаются темы, красивая анимация.

[image]
[image]

Нельзя не упомянуть и местное сообщество по Qt, которое не оставит в беде, буде таковая случится.

---

Небольшое дополнение в виду того, что в ответе был упущен момент, связанный с необходимостью рисования графиков, обозначенных в вопросе как сложные.

Из-за того, что ранее `QtCharts` поставлялся только по коммерческой лицензии, недостающий функционал брался в основном из сторонних, поддерживаемых OpenSource-сообществом проектов. Это и замечательный `QCustomPlot`, и многофункциональный `Qwt`, а также множество других, менее известных библиотек. Разумеется, все или большая часть из них доступны к использованию и сейчас.

Тем не менее, хотелось бы добавить пару слов и в защиту `QtCharts`, которую при поверхностном рассмотрении многие причисляют к вещи в себе. На самом деле это не так. `QtCharts` построен на базе функционала `QGraphicsScene` и соответственно может быть настроен для отображения практически любых типов графиков.

Comment: Добавлю, что Qt (на самом базовом уровне, достаточном для несложного GUI) вполне осваивается за неделю. При условии базовых же знаний C++, конечно.

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить о чистом С, то есть два варианта:

1. ncurses
2. gtk+

Первый вариант - под консоль, используется псевдографика
Второй вариант - полноценные графические приложения для оконного менеджера GTK+ в Linux.

Остальноё всё (Qt, WxWidget, MFC, ...) это для С++. Преподы ваши - придурки полные.

Насколько я ознакомился с этим списком заданий (сынуля позавчера притащил из Университета), там есть несколько заданий, НЕ связанных с GUI, чисто расчётных. Настоятельно рекомндую выбрать одно из них. Но, у них хотя бы, организовали недельные курсы по C#...

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вот, по поводу [рисования и анимации в MFC](http://words-are-dust.blogspot.ru/2012/01/c-mfc.html). Если делать через GDI, то принципиальной разницы алгоритма хоть с WinAPI, хоть C# / WindowsForms, не будет: для непрерывной функции ставим pen в начало графика, а дальше точка за точкой рисуем LineTo (попутно пересчивая и масштабируя точки из оконной системы координат в нашу). Но это если ехать поскорее, без сплайнов и прочего.

Для шашечек я бы действительно взял бы какой-нибудь Qt или WPF. Но, догадываюсь, что красивые-готовые компоненты графиков могут для вас не прокатить.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно только отобразить графики и не нужно вводить интерактивные данные в программу то можно воспользоваться графическими библиотеками [Cairo](https://www.cairographics.org/) или [SDL](http://libsdl.org/)